# TypeScript+React構成におけるMaterial-UIの型エラー

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### 概要

現在、React + TypeScript + Material-UIを用いた開発を行っていますが、エラーが発生致しました。Material-UIのCSS in JSを用いているのですが、その中の`toolbar`で下記の様なエラーが発生致しました。TSの型エラーだということは分かるのですが、解決方法は分からず…。
自分なりに色々調べてみましたが、問題に該当する記事が見つけられませんでした…。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願い致します。

### エラーの内容

```
型 'CSSProperties'を型 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties <{}> | （（props：{}）=> CreateCSSProperties <{}>） 'に割り当てことはできません。型' CSSProperties 'を型' CreateCSSProperties <{}> 'にレジストリことはできません。
```

### 該当するコード

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

// ここのtoolbarでエラーが発生
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
}))

const TopPage: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Root>
　　　 // ここのtoolbarでエラーが発生
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <H1>~ No Checkouts. ~</H1>
      <H1>自動販売機</H1>
    </Root>
  )
}

const Root = styled.div`
  padding-bottom: 50px;
`

const H1 = styled.h1`
  text-align: center;
`

export default TopPage
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: 次回以降の質問からで大丈夫ですが、質問される場合はライブラリやTypeScriptのバージョンなどを質問に書かれた方が良いと思いました。(Material-UIなどはバージョンによっても違いがあったりするので)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material-UI 4.9.0で確認しましたが、以下のようにすることでコンパイルエラーが解消するような気がします。

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  toolbar: {
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
}))
```

コンパイルエラーになってた原因としては、`theme.mixins.toolbar`の型は `React.CSSProperties`ですが、ここで期待されている型がMaterial-uiの`CSSProperties`なので、型が異なってエラーになっています。

そのため、スプレッド構文を使用して`theme.mixins.toolbar`のfieldを全て渡してあげることで、コンパイルエラーが解消されます。

---

ちなみに以下のPull requestで`theme.mixins.toolbar`の型がMaterial-uiの`CSSProperties`に変更されたので、次のバージョンなどからスプレッド構文を使わずに、そのまま渡せるように変わる(直る?)かもしれません。

[core] Fix mixins not being assignable as JSS styles by ririvas · Pull Request #19491 · mui-org/material-ui
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/19491